# Create Terraform Cloudwatch Dashboards dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

**Overview**

Currently, dashboards are being deployed via Terraform using values from a dictionary in locals.tf:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "my_alb" {
  for_each       = local.env_mapping[var.env]
  dashboard_name = "${each.key}_alb_web_operational"
  dashboard_body = templatefile("templates/alb_ops.tpl", {
    environment = each.value.env,
    account     = each.value.account,
    region      = each.value.region,
    alb         = each.value.alb
    tg          = each.value.alb_tg
  }
```

This leads to fragility because the values of AWS infrastructure resources like the ALB and ALB target group are hard coded.  Sometimes when applying updates AWS resources are destroyed and recreated.

**Question**

What's the best approach to get these values dynamically?  For example, this could be achieved by writing a Python/Boto3 Lambda, which looks up these values and then passes them to Terraform as env variables.  Are there any other recommended ways to achieve the same?

Comment: It largely depends. Is all of the code in the same root module? If not, are you defining outputs in modules? Using something external to terraform is bad design, unless there is not another way of doing the same thing, and usually there is.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much environment is *dynamical*. But sounds like Terraform [data sources](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources) is what you are looking for.

Usually, loadbalancer names are fixed or generated by some rule and should be known before creating dashboard.

Let's suppose that names are fixed, and names are:

```
variable "loadbalancers" {
  type = object
  default = {
    alb01 = "alb01",
    alb02 = "alb02"
  }
}
```

In this case [loadbalancers](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lb) may be taken by:

```
data "aws_lb" "albs" {
  for_each = var.loadbalancers
  name = each.value  # or each.key 
}
```

And after that you will be able to get dynamically generated parameters:

- `data.aws_lb["alb01"].id`
- `data.aws_lb["alb01"].arn`
- [etc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb#attributes-reference)

If loadbalancer names are generated by some rule, you should use `aws cli` or `aws cdk` to get all names, or just generate names by same rule as it was generated inside AWS environment and pass inside Terraform variable.

Notice: `terraform plan (apply, destroy)` will raise error if you pass non-existent name. You should check if LB with provided name exists.